# Firebase OrderBy and EqualTo different key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the Firebase RealTime Database and I have the following keys in my data.

```
joinDate
isVerified
otherInfo
```

Now what I want is to orderBy **joinDate** but only get keys that have **isVerified** = true

I have the following query

```
let localRef=ref.orderByChild("isVerified").equalTo(true);
```

But as firebase only allows one orderby function. The above query will orderBy "isVerified" key.

How to I achive this.

Thanks

Comment: client side with a loop/iteration?

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property, such as `"isVerified_joinDate": "true_20180218"` and then `ref.orderByChild("isVerified_joinDate").startAt("true_")`. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase